# Reading binary data from Mongodb using Ruby

Tags: ruby, node.js, mongodb, base64

I've a MEAN.JS app that writes binary data in a Mongodb (db version v2.6.5) using this chunk of code:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
if (this.password) {
    this.salt = new Buffer(crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64'), 'base64');
    this.password = this.hashPassword(this.password);
}

next(); })
```

Trying to read this binary data from the db with ruby (v 2.1.5 with mongo v1.11.1) I got a base64 decoding error:

```
2.1.5 :001 > Base64.strict_decode64(salt)

`unpack': invalid base64 (ArgumentError)
```

Trying to unpack *salt* in binary mode results in wrong data:

```
[239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 90, 239, 191, 189, 46, 120, 8, 239, 191, 189, 45, 239, 191, 189, 20, 221, 150, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 57]
```

30 chars instead of the original 16

It seems that mongo gem reads the binary data as UTF-8 string and broke it

How can I recover the original string from the stored buffer in mongodb?

```
crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('base64')
```